# how to write streamly xml file using serializer

Tags: java, android, xml

hi i need to write xml file in android app which add longitude latitude and heart rate

when i use it like this

declare:`public XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();`
init:

```
try {
            //we set the FileOutputStream as output for the serializer, using UTF-8 encoding
                    serializer.setOutput(outputStream, "UTF-8");
                    //Write <?xml declaration with encoding (if encoding not null) and standalone flag (if standalone not null)
                    serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
                    //set indentation option
                    serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
                    //start a tag called "root"
                    serializer.startTag(null, "root");
                    Log.e("Exception","++xml++ created xml file header");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception","++xml++ error occurred while creating xml file");
        }
```

procedure to end xml file:

```
final Button buttonEnd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEnd);
        buttonEnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //XmlSerializer serializer2 = Xml.newSerializer();  
                try{
                    serializer.setOutput(outputStream, "UTF-8");
                    //serializer.endTag(null, "root");
                    serializer.endDocument();
                    //write xml data into the FileOutputStream
                    serializer.flush();
                    serializer = null;
                    //finally we close the file stream
                    outputStream.close();
                    Log.d("HXMTEST", "+++++ end of creating xml");
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Exception","++xml++ error occurred while ending xml file");
                }
                if(mConnectThread != null){
                    mConnectThread.cancel();
                }

                textview3.setText("the monitoring has been cancelled");
            }
        });
```

procedure to add nodes:

```
public void AddNodes(String heartBeat, String latitude, String longitude){
        //serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        try{
         serializer.setOutput(outputStream, "UTF-8");
         serializer.startTag(null, "hb");
         if(heartBeat != null){
                 serializer.text(heartBeat);
             }else{
                 serializer.text("-1");
         }
         serializer.endTag(null, "hb");
         serializer.startTag(null, "latitude");
         if(latitude != null){
                 serializer.text(latitude);
             }else{
                 serializer.text("-1");
         }
         serializer.endTag(null, "latitude");
         serializer.startTag(null, "longitude");
         if(longitude != null){
                 serializer.text(longitude);
             }else{
                 serializer.text("-1");
         }
         serializer.endTag(null, "longitude");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception","++xml++ error occurred while adding xml file " +e.toString());
        }       
    }
```

it does not throw any exception but create only a bald xml file. i do not know why but when at the function which ends the saving i write `serializer.endTag(null, "root");`  it throws exception array out of bounds. it behaves like it does not save streamly the data.

**i need something like in objective C is `retain`**

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Simple Framework may be a good idea for you: http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php . You can create class like this one:

```
@Root
public class Example {
    @Element
    private int longitude;

    @Element
    private int latitude;

    @Element
    private int heartrate;

    @Attribute
    private int index;

    public Example() {
        super();
    }

    public Example(int longitude, int latitude, int heartrate, int index) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.heartrate = heartrate;
        this.index = index;
    }

    public int gelLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public int getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public int gelHeartrate() {
        return heartrate;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return index;
    }
}
```

And then after calling

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
Example example = new Example(1, 2, 3, 123);
File result = new File("example.xml");
serializer.write(example, result);
```

you'll get an xml file as:

```
<example index="123">
<latitude>1</latitude>
<longitude>2</longitude>
<heartrate>3</heartrate>
</example>
```

Comment: not exactly what i made but not bad :) i will post the solution as one optional answer later this week, but thanks a lot all of you

Answer (score 1):

I have not gone through your complete code, but you can get some guidance through this tutorial http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

Comment: thanks for the answer but it is not good for me i do not want to create a list and then save it i need to do that as soon as i got the data

Comment: Where do you call AddNodes method?

Comment: when i get the data i start thread which collect the data and send it back to the activity using handler.and then i call AddNodes(); so like

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems complicated for 3 little attributes, don't you think?
There are some easier ways to read/write XML with android, maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351218/unmarshalling-xml-files-into-java-objects-in-android) will helps.

Comment: I thank your answer but i can not accept it.I need to do it that way, but i thing if i do this thinks in separetly thread it could work