# marshalling and unmarshalling xml file in android

Tags: android, spring, rest, xml-serialization

I´m trying to use spring android to parse an xml that looks like that on my android code (to serialize/deserialize objects streaming from server and/or send them in post to the REST service):

```
<ROOT>
<USERNAME>user</USERNAME>
<INFOTYPE></INFOTYPE>
<DATA format='xml_field'>
<field name='field_id1'>1000</field>
<field name='field_id2'>xxx</field>
</DATA>
</ROOT>
```

I don´t know if it would be possible, but I really like this tool (spring android).

However, I would accept any easy solution that addresses my issue.

ps: I've already read other threads like this:
[Unmarshalling XML files into Java objects in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351218/unmarshalling-xml-files-into-java-objects-in-android)
and at the moment this looks like the best solution for my case: http://simple.sourceforge.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Spring reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html) basically answers your question:

> **2.2.4 Object to XML Marshaling**
>
> Object to XML marshaling in Spring Android RestTemplate requires the use of a third party XML mapping
> library. The Simple XML serializer is used to provide this marshaling
> functionality.

The easy way is to just pick up this suggestion and go with Simple. I've used it a couple of times myself and it's very easy to set up and has a fairly straightforward way of declaring the hierarchy using Java POJOs. (On a side note: I still prefer JSON though. :))

Alternatively it wouldn't require a lot of effort to implement (de)serializing using SAX, provided your xml structures are as simple as your example. This option will probably keep your code more compact.

Comment: have you actually used simple-xml with spring android? did it work well for you?

Comment: Nope, I haven't used Spring Android (at all) yet - I do have experience with Simple XML and Android projects though. That being said, I can't imagine the developers recommending Simple XML if it wouldn't work happily together with Spring.

Comment: @MH.  If you have time can you have a look on this question. I also have same kind of problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553432/put-request-from-android-using-spring-resttemplate