# How to do an http post passing complex objects?

Tags: android, http-post, asp.net-web-api

The code pasted below (from android snippets) is a typical example of how to do an http post passing a few simple parameters. The client is an Android client. This is typical of what I am able to find on the internet...

```
public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/api/TripLocker");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList&lt;NameValuePair&gt;(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

}

I need to pass more complex data.  I want to do an http post passing a TripLocker_s object containing maybe 500 TriplegModel_s objects in it.  The object's definition is pasted below...

```
public class TripLegModel_s
{ 
    public string ourDirection;  //SE, SW, SSW, etc. 
    public double longitude;
    public double latitude;
    public double altitude;
    public DateTimeOffset TimeStamp;
    public double speed;
}

public class TripLocker_s
{
    public ObservableCollection<TripLegModel_s> BreadCrums = new ObservableCollection<TripLegModel_s>();
}
```

How can I pass this object using HTTP POST?  BTW, the service is an ASP.NET Web api service.
Thanks, Gary

Comment: What data format does the web service accept?  Whichever format it is, you should pass your object like that.

Comment: One possible option: A single name/value pair: "myComplexObject" => myCrossPlatformSerializedStringUrlEncoded.  IOW, serialize the whole object into a format ASP.NET code can understand (i.e., NOT Java-specific), then URL-encode it and pass the result as a single POST parameter.  Serialization may be done with a JAXB alternative (JAXB is too heavy for an APK): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351218/unmarshalling-xml-files-into-java-objects-in-android .

Answer (score 1):

Convert to/from JSON. Thats the best way.   http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/  Its fast as lightning.

Comment: I did that.  Now I have my object represented as a json string.  Now my question stands as "how can I pass that in a HTTP Post.  Or as an argument in an HTTP URL?